# PHP random number not working

Tags: php, html, image, random, input

I want to write a php code that displays a random image and the person has to guess what it is. The problem is my php code tells me that the right city is incorrect, i cant figure out why

```
<?php
$random = rand(1, 3);
$answer ;
if ($random == 1) { $answer = "chicago" ;} 
elseif($random == 2) {$answer = "LA" ;}
elseif($random == 3) {$answer = "NewYork" ;}
else {echo "Answer is None" ; } 
if (isset($_POST["choice"])) {
    $a = $_POST["choice"];
    if($a ==$answer){
    echo "<br> working <br>" ; 
    }else {echo "<br> Not Working <br>";}

}
 ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>City Guess</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<img src="four/Image_<?php echo $random ;?>.jpg" width="960" height="639" alt=""/>

<form action="" method="POST">
chicago <input type= "radio" name="choice" value="chicago"  />
<br>
LA <input type= "radio" name="choice" value="LA" />
<br>
NewYork <input type= "radio" name="choice" value="NewYork" />
<br>
<input type ="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ist because your $random resets on every page load so say first load picks 1 when the form is posted it picks 3.  You need to store the $random of the first load i nyour form and pass that in as your "correct" result in a hidden field then compare your submitted answer to the random answer

Comment: This function rand is returning a float between 1 and 3, not 1, 2 or 3. You need use something like floor($random).

Comment: random will generate a new random number of page load. Whay might be useful is using a session/cookie to store this number, or finding another way. A database driven approach will generate lots of rows but will hit your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your logic, you do not store the generated number that is used to show the image, instead you generate a new number every time you open the page.

You should store the generated number in (for example...) a session to preserve it and use that to compare.

Answer (score 2):

You're generating your random value **EVERYTIME** the page is loaded. e.g. when the person first visits it and gets the form, you generate `2`. When the form is submitted, you generate ANOTHER value, and this time it's `3`. So even though the user correctly answers `2`, you say they're wrong because the you've forgotten what you originally asked.

You need to store the generated value somehow, and compare that to the response, e.g.

```
$rand = rand(1,3);

<input type="hidden" name="correct_answer" value="$rand">


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST') {
   if ($_POST['correct_answer'] == $_POST['user_answer']) {
        echo 'correct';
   }
}
```

Comment: That's probably how some of the online games are "rigged" ;-)

Comment: Still getting the same error with . if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST') {
   if ($_POST['correct_answer'] == $_POST['choice']) {
        echo 'correct';
   } else {echo 'Not correct' ;}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$random = floor(rand(1, 4));
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following hidden field in your form, using `value="<?php echo $answer ?>"` and it will work with your present code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="correct_answer" value="<?php echo $answer ?>">
```

Matter 'o fact, you don't even need `name="correct_answer"`

Just do:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $answer ?>">
```

Remember when you test this, you have a **"1 in 3"** chance for success!

---

### Edit

Here's the code that I used:

```
<?php
$random = rand(1, 3);
$answer;
if ($random == 1) { $answer = "chicago" ;} 
elseif($random == 2) {$answer = "LA" ;}
elseif($random == 3) {$answer = "NewYork" ;}
else {echo "Answer is None" ; } 
if (isset($_POST["choice"])) {
    $a = $_POST["choice"];
    if($a ==$answer){
    echo "<br> working <br>" ; 
    }else {echo "<br> Not Working <br>";}
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>City Guess</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<img src="four/Image_<?php echo $random ;?>.jpg" width="960" height="639" alt=""/>

<form action="" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $answer ?>">

chicago <input type= "radio" name="choice" value="chicago"  />
<br>
LA <input type= "radio" name="choice" value="LA" />
<br>
NewYork <input type= "radio" name="choice" value="NewYork" />
<br>
<input type ="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Which "error" is that? @user3450126 You need to be specific about errors.

Comment: When the echo "your correct " ; should come up. It says ur incorrect. I echoed the answer so i know that the answers match. Maybe you should try to take my code and input ur idea on how to get it to work. That would be so much help. I would really appropriate it. Im new to php and i would love/ need some help

Comment: Look under my **Edit** for the code that I used. I never got an error myself from it. @user3450126

Comment: If my shown code still throws an error, I suspect it will have something to do with `<img src="four/Image_<?php echo $random ;?>.jpg" width="960" height="639" alt=""/>` because I don't know how you're using that, I didn't include in my own test. @user3450126